# Remove index.php from url using .htaccess for urls 127.0.0.1

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I have my url in this way

```
http://127.0.0.1:420/github/myproject/users
```

and my .htacess file has the following code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /github/myproject
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|style|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA] 
</IfModule>
```

Can you anyone help me how to write the RewriteRule expression that suits my url ? thanks for you help in advance

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line on the top:

```
RewriteRule ^/github/myproject/(.*)$ /github/myproject/index.php/$1 [NC]
```

So it will become:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^/github/myproject/(.*)$ /github/myproject/index.php/$1 [NC]
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    RewriteBase /github/myproject
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|style|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA] 
</IfModule>
```

Please tell me if it works for you!

Comment: No it did not help actually. I am getting an error page when I open
http://127.0.0.1:420/github/myproject/users

I want a regular expression which matches my url in .htaccess
I am glad you are helping

Comment: Okay, could you please give two examples where you say which URL you want the user to visit, and which URL you want .htaccess to transform it into?

Comment: I have a url in this way
<code>http://127.0.0.1:420/github/myproject/index.php/users</code>

now using .htaccess file I want users to visit the same page even if it is <code>http://127.0.0.1:420/github/myproject/users</code>

which exactly means I want to discard the index.php term from my url

Comment: I've updated my answer. Since I don't know much about your project, I made a one-liner that should do the job for you without changing much of your code.